# Motherboard On-Board Video Issues

Tags: video, motherboard

I have a FoxConn N15235 Motherboard. The PC works fine with an added video card, i.e.:
Boots Perfectly and Video outputs via the  AGP video card

However i am unable to get any video via Onboard VGA.
I've even tried removing the AGP Video card but still no luck.

How can I get the on board VGA adaptor working?

Comment: That mobo has almost no support online!  However, have you installed the driver for the onboard video?  You may need to figure out which exact video it is and search online for the drivers from the chipset's site.

Comment: It looks like the motherboard model number is P4M800P7MB-RS2H

Comment: @nerdwaller - he would have had at least bios, when connected properly - regardless of any drivers.

Comment: @Jook Yes, you are right.  Then in the OS they will need the drivers for it to properly function as well, I didn't want to be redundant of you but my comment was not a full answer either.

Comment: @nerdwaller ok :) i did not get that - np ...

Comment: @Jook No worries, I voted you up, you're 100% right to verify that.  Thanks man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you changed the preferences in your BIOS settings?

It should look something like this:

[image: bios setting]

unfortunately, there is not much of documentation on your motherboard - please refer to your manual or post, what bios + version your motherboard is running.

And not that I would suspect it, but please make a 100% sure, that your monitor+cable + connection to the onBoard vga-port is correct.

Comment: hey everyone, thanks for the quick responses:
ok so just to clarify:
1. I DO NOT have video even during POST and BIOS.
2. I am downloading the manual as we speak
3. and yes, sorry I just found out that the motherboard IS called P4M800P7MB-RS2H
4. I will check the bios settings in a bit and post back!
5. Support for this mobo is (sh*t) limited :)

thanks, be back in a few

Comment: Ok so just to keep everyone in the loop:
I have checked the BIOS settings and the only onboard configurations relate to:
1. On-Board LAN Controller
2. On-Board LAN Boot ROM
3. On-Board Audio Controller

I have however noticed that there is a setting that looks like this:
'Initiate Graphics Adapter'
and is set to PCIE/PCI as opposed to the only other option PCI/PCIE.

I've scoured, yes scoured :), the bios settings and have found nothing remotely close to getting on-board video enabled... :(

Thanks @Jook.
any other suggestions?

Comment: Initiate Graphics Adapter settings toggle does not help

Comment: is your BIOS version 5B4F1P20? have you seen the option from page 31? `Init Display First` - and from page 35 `Output Port` - and page 37 `VIA OnChip PCI Device`

Comment: and page 48 might(!) have an influence `Assign IRQ For VGA/USB`

Comment: Hey @Jook, I've checked my BIOS on this system, ver. 8.0.0.15, i don't know what it is according to the FoxConn website. Anyways I don't have those options. Downloading the latest BIOS release from their site and I will definitely give it a go. Thanks for all your help, take a +1 from me :)

Comment: I'm finding FoxConn to be ridiculous!!! ag, now i have to load (holding my breath) Windows then update the BIOS then Install Ubuntu again. such is life, thanks alot for all your help everyone!

 P.S. Don't Buy FoxConn!!!! Only because their websites make us Indian people look like we're still living in the 80's. Yuk